# Storing time series data, without a database

Tags: perl, datetime, time-series

I would like to store time series data, such as CPU usage over 6 Months (Will poll the CPU usage every 2 minutes, so later I can get several resolutions, such as - 1 Week, 1 Month, or even higher resolutions, 5 Minutes,etc).

I'm using Perl, and I dont want to use RRDtool or relational database, I was thinking of implementing my own using some sort of a circular buffer (ring buffer) with the following properties:

1. 6 Months = 186 Days = 4,464 Hours = 267,840 Minutes.
2. Dividing it into 2 minutes sections: 267,840 / 2 = 133,920.
3. 133,920 is the ring-buffer size.
4. Each element in the ring-buffer will be a hashref with the key as the epoch (converted easily into date time using `localtime`) and the value is the CPU usage for that given time.
5. I will serialize this ring-buffer (using `Storable` I guess)

Any other suggestions?
Thanks,

Comment: I strongly encourage you to use a database. SQLite requires no server

Answer (score 10):

I suspect you're overthinking this.  Why not just use a flat (e.g.) TAB-delimited file with one line per time interval, with each line containing a timestamp and the CPU usage?  That way, you can just append new entries to the file as they are collected.

If you want to automatically discard data older than 6 months, you can do this by using a separate file for each day (or week or month or whatever) and deleting old files.  This is more efficient than reading and rewriting the entire file every time.

---

Writing and parsing such files is trivial in Perl.  Here's some example code, off the top of my head:

#### Writing:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw'strftime';

my $dir = '/path/to/log/directory';

my $now = time;
my $date = strftime '%Y-%m-%d', gmtime $now;  # ISO 8601 datetime format
my $time = strftime '%H:%M:%S', gmtime $now;

my $data = get_cpu_usage_somehow();

my $filename = "$dir/cpu_usage_$date.log";

open FH, '>>', $filename
    or die "Failed to open $filename for append: $!\n";

print FH "${date}T${time}\t$data\n";

close FH or die "Error writing to $filename: $!\n";
```

#### Reading:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw'strftime';

my $dir = '/path/to/log/directory';

foreach my $filename (sort glob "$dir/cpu_usage_*.log") {
    open FH, '<', $filename
        or die "Failed to open $filename for reading: $!\n";
    while (my $line = <FH>) {
        chomp $line;
        my ($timestamp, $data) = split /\t/, $line, 2;
        # do something with timestamp and data (or save for later processing)
    }
}
```

(Note: I can't test either of these example programs right now, so they might contain bugs or typos.  Use at your own risk!)

Answer (score 2):

As @Borodin suggests, use SQLite or `DBM::Deep` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680241/perl-dbm-vs-storable).

If you want to stick to Perl itself, go with [DBM::Deep](https://metacpan.org/module/DBM::Deep):

> A unique flat-file database module, written in pure perl. ... Can handle millions of keys and unlimited levels without significant slow-down. Written from the ground-up in pure perl -- this is NOT a wrapper around a C-based DBM. Out-of-the-box compatibility with Unix, Mac OS X and Windows.

You mention your need for storage, which could be satisfied by a simple text file as advocated by @llmari. (And, of course, using a CSV format would allow the file to be manipulated easily in a spreadsheet.)

But, if you plan on collecting *a lot of data*, and you wish to eventually be able to *query it with good performance*, then go with a tool designed for that purpose.